# how to get a short nth prime number code in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code that runs in ruby:

```
require'prime'
$<.each{|x|p Prime.take(x.to_i).last}
```

but I want a shorter code.
I've tried to use get_nth_prime() but I don't find the right syntax.
Also is there a shorter input?

Answer (score 2):

There are different (and arguably better) ways to get the n<sup>th</sup> prime in Ruby, but none that are much shorter. In the end there's no way to calculate the n<sup>th</sup> prime without counting the first n−1 primes, which I suppose is why Ruby makes you go through the motions. You can see some good solutions on the duplicate question linked above.

As to your other question:

> is there a shorter input?

That depends on your use case. `$<` is a special variable in Ruby; it's an alias for [`ARGF`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/ARGF.html), which does *a lot*. `$<.each` will iterate all of the lines in the files given on the command line, so e.g.:

```sh
$ cat a.txt
1
2
3

$ cat b.txt
7
88
999

$ ruby -r prime -e "$<.each{|x| p Prime.take(x.to_i).last }" a.txt b.txt
2
3
5
17
457
7907
```

(If you don't give any file names, `ARGF` will try to read from STDIN.)

I suspect you're trying to do something simpler, though.

Are you just trying to print a single prime number given a single input? In that case, you could do this:

```
require "prime"
n = STDIN.each_line.first.to_i
p Prime.take(n).last
```

```sh
$ echo 999 | ruby script.rb
7907
```

It might be nicer, though, to take input as a command line argument. In that case you can use `ARGV` (alias `$*`), which is an array of the command line arguments:

```
require "prime"
n = ARGV[0].to_i
p Prime.take(n).last
```

```sh
$ ruby script.rb 999
7907
```

Comment: I need to iterate on multiple numbers n given in stdin, not on n given as an argument to my script

Comment: Alright, then. As I wrote, the code you have does that. Cheers! (Of course, if you're doing that you may want to memoize the primes for performance, especially if your input has a known upper bound.)